# how to avoid picking old date in datetime picker in inline vfpage

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, datetime

I have a date time picker as a calendar. is there anyway that i avoid backdating in the calendar ? 
It should be only pick today and future dates.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if there is a way to have a client side restriction on date range. Alternatively you can apply a `validation rule` on the field to keep the data as you need.
If your field is of type `Date`, 
`Your_Field < TODAY()` 
If your field is of type `DateTime`, 
`DATEVALUE(Your_Field) < TODAY()`

Also make sure to do the data cleanup for the existing data if you are applying such a validation. If not the reports will show unacceptable data to your managers ;)

Comment: If you have a `DateTime` field and you are going to do a data migration for that, take care about the timezone difference. Because we should consider that Saleforce keeps `DateTime` field values as `GMT` and they will be converted into user's timezone when rendering on pages

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to control the date picker in salesforce.I think you neeed to use jquery calendar to avoid backdating.

http://jsfiddle.net/antelopelovefan/ZW7cs/34/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#Date').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        //Get today's date at midnight
        var today = new Date();
        today = Date.parse(today.getMonth()+1+'/'+today.getDate()+'/'+today.getFullYear());
        //Get the selected date (also at midnight)
        var selDate = Date.parse(dateText);

        if(selDate < today) {
            //If the selected date was before today, continue to show the datepicker
            $('#Date').val('');
            $(inst).datepicker('show');
        }
    }
});
```

});